# Button not directing to the email in react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a react app. In that i have a button, i want if someone clicks on that one then it takes him to compose email. But it is not working. This is but i tried to do

`<button className="btn_2" > <a href="mailto:my_email@gmail.com" > Say Hello </a> </button>`

Comment: It just active activates the default mail client on the computer for sending an e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked  and the code is working fine. But one thing I observed is you have to click on the anchor text (a tag) and not the other part of button. To avoid this you can remove button as a wrapper element, use `a` tag and style it using css.

```css
a{
  display: inline-block;
  padding:.5rem;
  background: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="mailto:my_email@gmail.com" > Say Hello </a>
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it still does not work. But when I right click on the anchor tag and then open it in new tab then again it doesn't work, but after just clicking on the url and pressing the enter it works.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because is not valid HTML5 according to [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element).

> The a element can be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g., buttons or other links).

You probably should replace with:

```
<a className="btn_2" href="mailto:my_email@gmail.com"> Say Hello </a>
```